# Animation and Hit Registration issues with 2d fighting platformer

Tags: javascript, function, animation, game-development

I have been working on a 2D fighting game, and it has been mostly going well, except for a few issues. I am working on 3 separate JavaScript pages, and one HTML page. My issues are present in the death sequence and animation for my two player sprites, as well as in the accuracy of my players hit boxes and attack boxes. I have tried many solutions and can't seem to find one.

I have mostly been following this tutorial if anyone needs it for reference.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyqbNFMDRGQ&t=11835s

**Death Animation:**
Tried to animate the death for each sprite, the same way I did for my other animations (which all work fine), but nothing happens on player death.

**Hitboxes and Attack Boxes:**
I have tried to make two separate functions for my players actual hit boxes around their body, i.e where they will take damage from if they are hit, and also the attack boxes for the players attack animations, to determine whether the attack hits the opposing players hitbox and does damage.

Comment: https://github.com/james-shortt/Fighting-Game-Project

Comment: Above link to my GitHub repository with the code files

Comment: Please post the exact code that gives you problems here in the question, in such a way that others can also experience the same bug as you do. It's a bit much to ask others to go through your whole project to find the bug for you. Also that external link might break one day, making this question useless to other SO users.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.